# Dash Python how to make multiple updating graphs, how to title

Tags: python, graph, label, plotly-dash

new coder here, I'm trying to make 4 graphs that share the same random data (although I plan on splitting them apart later). When it was just the one graph it took the random data fine and automatically scaled. In the go.layout there's no way to put which graph you're labeling. Now that I've added multiple none of them have any titles, axis labels, or data. Please help!

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.express as px
import random
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from collections import deque
#setting first points
X = deque(maxlen = 20)
X.append(1)
Y = deque(maxlen = 20)
Y.append(1)
#app settings, html layout
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
  
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1([
        html.H1(children='Graphs'),
        dcc.Graph(id = 'Battery Voltage', animate = True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id = 'graph-update',
            interval = 1000,
            n_intervals = 0
        ),
    ],
),
html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id = 'Signal', animate = True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id = 'graph-update2',
            interval = 1000,
            n_intervals = 0
        ),
    ],
),
html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id = 'Health', animate = True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id = 'graph-update3',
            interval = 1000,
            n_intervals = 0
        ),
    ],
),
html.Div(
    [
        dcc.Graph(id = 'Prognastics', animate = True),
        dcc.Interval(
            id = 'graph-update4',
            interval = 1000,
            n_intervals = 0
        ),
    ],
)])

#this is what keeps the graph updating 
@app.callback(
    [Output('Battery Voltage', 'figure'),
     Output('Signal', 'figure'),
     Output('Health', 'figure'),
     Output('Prognastics', 'figure')],
    [ Input('graph-update', 'n_intervals'),
      Input('graph-update2', 'n_intervals'),
      Input('graph-update3', 'n_intervals'),
      Input('graph-update4', 'n_intervals')]
)
  
def update_graph_scatter(n):

    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))
    data = go.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(Y),
            name='Scatter',
            mode= 'lines+markers'
    )
  
    return {'data': [data],
            'layout' : go.Layout(title="Battery Voltage",
                                 xaxis_title="Time",
                                 yaxis_title="Voltage",
                                 xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                 yaxis = dict(range = [min(Y),max(Y)])
                                 )
            }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

[When ran with multiple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PSVS.png)

[Just the one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3cO1.png)

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else has this problem, the definition has to come immediately after their callback. My formatting was also bad I guess. It should look like:

```
@app.callback(Output('Health', 'figure'),
              Input('graph-update3', 'n_intervals'))

def update_graph3(n): 
    X.append(X[-1]+1)
    Y.append(Y[-1]+Y[-1] * random.uniform(-0.1,0.1))
    #those are random points, we'd socket something in
    data = go.Scatter(
            x=list(X),
            y=list(Y),
            name='Scatter',
            mode= 'lines+markers'
    )
    print("data:", data)
    return {'data': [data],
            'layout' : go.Layout(title="Health",
                                 xaxis_title="Time",
                                 yaxis_title="Health",
                                 xaxis=dict(range=[min(X),max(X)]),
                                 yaxis = dict(range = [min(Y),max(Y)])
                                 )
            }
```